# How do i change this because they group together again

Tags: python, xml

So i have try another method today, i was trying to output the XML content of the restaurant name and address of all restaurant,
Here is my code

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
 
# We're at the root node (<page>)
root_node = ET.parse('record.xml').getroot()
 
# We need to go one level below to get <items>
# and then one more level from that to go to <item>
for tag in root_node.findall('restaurant'):
    value = tag.attrib['name']
    print("Restaurant name:")
    print(value)
    for tag in root_node.findall('restaurant/address'):
        print(tag.text)
```

But the output will be like this

```
Restaurant name:
La Pasteria
8, Jalan Mata Kuching, 89200 Selangor
21, Jalan Taming Sari, 75350 Melaka  
25, Jalan Bukit Beruang, 75450 Melaka
22, Jalan Ayer Keroh, 7520 Melaka    
Restaurant name:
Nyonya Baba
8, Jalan Mata Kuching, 89200 Selangor
21, Jalan Taming Sari, 75350 Melaka  
25, Jalan Bukit Beruang, 75450 Melaka
22, Jalan Ayer Keroh, 7520 Melaka    
Restaurant name:
Malaya Food
8, Jalan Mata Kuching, 89200 Selangor
21, Jalan Taming Sari, 75350 Melaka  
25, Jalan Bukit Beruang, 75450 Melaka
22, Jalan Ayer Keroh, 7520 Melaka    
PS D:\python file>
```

I know maybe i am using the wrong code at here but i dont know how to change it

```
for tag in root_node.findall('restaurant/address'):
    print(tag.text)
```

Here is my xml code

```
<record>
   <restaurant name="La Pasteria" rate="-">
      <cuisine id="-">Italian</cuisine>
      <address>8, Jalan Mata Kuching, 89200 Selangor</address>
      <capacity>300</capacity>
      <phone>06-2899808</phone>
      <phone>06-2829818</phone>
         <general>-</general>
         <shop1>-</shop1>
         <shop2>-</shop2>
   </restaurant>
   <restaurant name="Nyonya Baba" rate="3">
      <cuisine id="112">Malaysian</cuisine>
      <address>21, Jalan Taming Sari, 75350 Melaka</address>
      <address>25, Jalan Bukit Beruang, 75450 Melaka</address>
      <capacity>80</capacity>
      <phone>
      <general>012-2677498</general>
         <shop1>06-2855413</shop1>
         <shop2>06-2856418</shop2>
      </phone>
   </restaurant>
   <restaurant name="Malaya Food" rate="5">
      <cuisine id="115">Malaysian</cuisine>
      <address>22, Jalan Ayer Keroh, 7520 Melaka</address>
      <capacity>50</capacity>
      <phone>06-2723603</phone>
         <general>-</general>
         <shop1>-</shop1>
         <shop2>-</shop2>
   </restaurant>
</record>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there; just change your inside loop from

```
for tag in root_node.findall('restaurant/address'):
        print(tag.text)
```

to

```
 for address in tag.findall('.//address'):
        print(address.text)
```

Output should be

```
Restaurant name:
La Pasteria
8, Jalan Mata Kuching, 89200 Selangor
Restaurant name:
Nyonya Baba
#note: in your xml, this restaurant has two different addresses, for some reason
21, Jalan Taming Sari, 75350 Melaka
25, Jalan Bukit Beruang, 75450 Melaka
Restaurant name:
Malaya Food
22, Jalan Ayer Keroh, 7520 Melaka
```